# Updating deeply nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema for events with signups that saves its data like this

```
...
"slots" : {
        "red" : {
            "groups" : [ ]
        },
        "blue" : {
            "groups" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("552d742588feb73b7e496ee5"),
                    "name" : "Group 1"
                    "players" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("552d742588feb73b7e496ee7"),
                            "role" : "Leader",
                            "player" : null
                        },
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("552d742588feb73b7e496ee6"),
                            "role" : "Observer",
                            "player" : null
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("552d742588feb73b7e496edc"),
                    ....
```

- The maximum amount of slots for all groups are 99 in one collection
- 'groups' are unique per collection
- Player references a User ID.
- The 'player' in any group can be reserved by users and kicked by admins.

Is this a good way of saving the data?

How would an update query look to remove or add a player if only ObjectId was available?

Comment: you have two ObjectId:1. for groups and 2. for player.Depending on which ObjectId you want to update??

Comment: @Subham the player ID

Comment: try $pull and $push .check these url :http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push

Comment: @Subham It's two arrays and I don't know the index to update, and $ will only work for one array. Would I have to find the group first and then update the units? How would that look like

Comment: yes,in this case, you have to find and update it manually.First find the group and take it as a json ,then modify or update  the json and delete the previous one from database and save the modified json.